Inner classes and garbage collection: behavior differences between Java 8 and latest Java
I had an interview today, and the interviewer presented the following code. They asked what the output would be in Java 8 and the latest version of Java.
From my understanding, since B is an inner class (non-static nested class), it holds a reference to the instance of A, which prevents A from being garbage collected (GC). This behavior is expected in Java 8. However, the interviewer demonstrated that A can be garbage collected in the latest version of Java (Java 23). He then asked in which version of Java this change occurred and why A can now be GC'd. I believe this behavior is either related to the new mechanism of inner classes (a is GC'd even when b is still alive. In principle, b should hold reference to a) or the new garbage collection process. However, I don't know the answer.
class A {
    class B {
        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("B destroy");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("A destroy");
    }
}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        A a = new A();
        A.B b = a.new B();
        a = null;
        System.gc();
        System.out.println("finish gc");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("finish sleep");
    }
}

Output of Java 8
finish gc
finish sleep

Output of Java 23
finish gc
A destroy
finish sleep


"interviewer presented the following code ..." - He was showing off.  That's bad interviewing technique.   And note that this could be due to the finalizers.  There are no guarantees that finalizers are executed in any particular order or any particular time.

Yes, this is either a "fit" question, to see how you deal with difficult (or impossible) problems.  Or they already had a candidate and wanted to make sure they had an excuse to not hire you.

@markspace I understand. However, from a knowledge-based perspective, how can this phenomenon be explained? It seems quite counterintuitive, since a should be destroyed after b

In principle, both objects are eligible to garbage collection and since finalizers may run in arbitrary order and after an arbitrary amount of time, both results are possible in both versions. You get this predictable outcome because the main method rarely gets optimized on common JVMs (as it will complete quickly anyway). You already found the reason for the specific reproducible behavior of this scenario yourself…

By experimenting with each version of Java from 23 downwards, I discovered that this phenomenon started in Java 18. I then looked up the new features of Java 18.
Enclosing Instance Fields Omitted from Inner Classes That Don't Use Them
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/18-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8271623

Prior to JDK 18, when javac compiles an inner class it always generates a private synthetic field with a name starting with this$ to
hold a reference to the enclosing instance, even if the inner class
does not reference its enclosing instance and the field is unused.
Starting in JDK 18, unused this$ fields are omitted; the field is only
generated for inner classes that reference their enclosing instance.


So effectively, if a non-static nested class doesn't reference its enclosing instance, it behaves the same as a static nested class.

Unless it’s serializable. Then, it will keep a reference for compatibility.
